# How do I show the terminal after a script is executed at startup?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm executing a bash script through a custom created service. At user login, the script is executed. I can verify that the program is running with the ps -ef command.

The only thing I want to have happen is, I want the Terminal to open and display the output of the script execution.

I am new to Linux. Still getting to know things. Not a very good experience so far.

Running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This aught to work `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "command"`

Comment: Where exactly do I put this? in the .sh file? The script runs an executable. The script looks like this:

`code`#!/bin/sh
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
./ethdcrminer64`code`

Comment: Yes in the bash file

Comment: Not working for me. I changed it to: `code'#!/bin/sh export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100 gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./ethdcrminer64"

Now it does't execute at all.

P.S. I can't seem to get the code mini-markdown right -_-

Comment: How did you create the user service ? Via `.desktop` file /startup applications menu, or `systemd` service ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy systemd service.

Answer (score 0):

Let me use this simple example to demonstrate one way of having that done:

1. Two scripts:

   - `launcher.sh`, and
   - `sample.sh`
2. Content of scripts:

   - `launcher.sh`:

     ```
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
     gnome-terminal --working-directory="/home/georgek/Documents/askubuntu" -- '--rcfile ./setup.bash ./launcher.sh'
     ```
   - `sample.sh`:

     ```
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
     du -h ./; read line;
     ```
3. Call `sample.sh` from `launcher.sh` like this: `launcher.sh` and that will pass the file `sample.sh` to the terminal, **note:** the `read line` prevents `gnome-terminal` from closig till you press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. Modify as it as you like.

**NOTE:**
   - `--` is preferred to `-x` as reported by bash
   - `--working-directory="/home/georgek/Documents/askubuntu"` tells terminal to run command from this directory.

- Use this file to set variables, from `man bash`:

  > --rcfile file
  >             Execute commands from file instead of the system wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and  the  standard  personal  initialization
  >             file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see INVOCATION below).

Comment: I am not getting this right. I got sample.sh to run from launcher.sh, but when I tried on my own script, terminal opens but nothing happens in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to install `screen` or `byobu` for nicer UI, and run your script there:

```
screen -S sessionname -d -m /path/to/script
```

This will let you reattach to session with

```
screen -r sessionname
```

Considering the fact that you're starting it from systemd service, you may need to have two things done: either allow multiuser session for everyone or configure individual access only for your username. This will need to have custom config file and pass that to screen with `-c` flag.

See also:

- https://superuser.com/q/454907/418028
- https://serverfault.com/a/155343/363611